# According to the AP styleguide should the degree symbol by omitted when writing the GPS coordinates in decimal degrees?

Tags: symbols

The closest answer I could find was the wikipedia entry for decimal degrees which states that in most systems the degree symbol is omitted.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U, but if you're asking a question about the AP Stylebook, the best place to check is the AP Stylebook. AP basically never uses the degree symbol— not for temperature, not for wind direction, not for latitude and longitude.

Comment: This is a question about a technical convention for writing symbols, not about the English language

Comment: And what is AP? Acute pancreatitis, the name of a French rapper, Academic Press?

Comment: Isn't Acute Pancreatitis also the name of a French rapper?